# How to use django groups in order to set group permission

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I want to use django groups provided in user groups. The django group permissions set in admin panel. Suppose I created two groups teachers and students. I want to set permissions at generic view level. Some views can only be can view or can edit by either student or teacher. These permission were set in django admin as following:
[image]

Now I created a createview as following:

```js
class CreateQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
 model =   Question
 success_url= reverse_lazy('questions:list')
 fields = ['title','description' ]
 def form_valid(self,form):
  form.instance.user = self.request.user
  #self.object.save()
  return super().form_valid(form)
```

Now I want this view to be accessible by only teacher groups. I cant find a proper way to implement group permission.Something like `@group_required` may work in this case [link](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10508/) but cant find any related documentation. What is correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [the PermissionRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin):

```
class CreateQuestionView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    permission = "yourapp.perm_code_name"
    model =   Question
    success_url= reverse_lazy('questions:list')
    fields = ['title','description' ]
    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        #self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note that you do **NOT** want to test whether your user belongs to a given group (assuming this group has specific perms) - this is an antipattern. All you care about is whether your user has the required perm, however he has it.

Comment: It would not make much sense if I have to set permission at each individual user level. The required solution would be to add user to group and set permissions at group level. What should preferred project architecture in this case. Why is it anti pattern?

Comment: Who talked about setting permissions per user ??? Of course you can use groups to set them (and preferably do so) - if you read the doc, you'll find out that `User.has_perm(codename)` checks ALL the user's perms - whether sets on the user or obtained from one of it's groups...

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks. I just reviewed the docs and understood your solution

Comment: Reading the doc is usually a good starting point indeed - not always enough, but still a good starting point ;-)